# How we can deploy einstein bot from one sandbox to other sandbox using change set?

Tags: lightning, community, sales, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page

I want to deploy my Einstein chat bot from one sandbox to other sandbox using change set. Can someone help me the steps how we can deploy chatbot using change set ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you finding some component of a chatbot is not supported by Change Sets? Please [edit] your question to be more specific about the problem

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by David,  please update question. Meanwhile you can check below details.

We can deploy bots using change set as mentioned [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets.htm)

- From Setup,  Enter outbound change sets in the Quick Find box, then
  select Outbound Change Sets.
- Select the 'Bot' change set.
- From the Change Set Components section, Click Add button.
- From the 'Component Type' drop down, select 'Bot'
- Check the components then click 'Add to Change Set'
- From the 'Profile Settings For Included Components' section, click Add Profiles then add the profiles that you want this deployment be visible to.
- Click Upload.

Thanks